# How to open a facebook\instagram page \ profile from your app? (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, info.plist, lsapplicationqueriesschemes

I'm trying to open a facebook page from my app. Here is the code:

```
let facebookWebURL = URL.init(string: "https://www.facebook.com/aviramnet")
let facebookAppURL = URL.init(string: "fb://profile/220780122049926")

if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(facebookAppURL!)){
    UIApplication.shared.open(facebookAppURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}else{
    UIApplication.shared.open(facebookWebURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

But it only opens the app on Safari browser. Did I miss something?

And yes, I have the Facebook app installed.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add in the app's info.plist :

under the **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** array add an item:

***fb*** for facebook, and ***instagram*** for instagram :

[image]